# How to put images on database MYSQL

Tags: android, mysql, database

Just wanted to ask how can I put an image on my database in MYSQL. I've been using eclipse to develop our project but I'am having troubles with putting a picture on my database.

I mean i already have an existing database but i need to include a picture/image in each row that I have. Is it possible?

Comment: In most cases, you don't want the actual image in the DB.  You'd want to save the image in a specific location, and have the DB field contain that location.

Comment: @cHao Sorry to ask this but I'm kinda new to programming, so can you please show me an example how to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a Column of type `BLOB` in your `Database Model` and save `byte[]` in it to store a Picture in each Row